# "Error converting to int" when casting to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why would I be getting an error message involving the data type INT when casting to decimal?

```
SELECT
    a.number, --nvarchar
    b.number  --nvarchar
FROM
    TableA AS a
    TableB AS b
WHERE
    CAST(COALESCE(a.number, 0), AS DECIMAL(10,2)) <> CAST(COALESCE(b.number, 0), AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

The error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 156
>       Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '78000.0' to data type 
>       int.

Comment: `COALESCE(a.number, 0)` will cause an implicit cast to `int`. Why are you storing decimals as strings in the first place? And given that you are why are you converting them before doing the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `coalesce` expects `a.number`, an `nvarchar`, to be compatible with `0`, an `int`. That is where the conversion fails, because `nvarchar` and `int` are incompatible.

Replacing `0` with `'0'` should fix the problem:

```
CAST(COALESCE(a.number, `0`), AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

**Note:** Unless this is a legacy database of which you have no control, you should consider changing the type of the `number` field to be, well, a number - for example, a `decimal(10,2)`.

Comment: nvarchar and int aren't inherently incompatible - just they have a value in it that doesn't cast to int. Presumably as it has a decimal component.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like because you are doing a Coalese on the number fields (which are nvarchar) and a number, your 0.  Move your cast to inside the Coalese (or cast the column that is nvarchar as well.

Doing this, gives me a conversion error because you can not coalese a string and a number

```
SELECT COALESCE('A', 0) -- errors out, and this is basically what your doing

SELECT
    a.number, --nvarchar
    b.number  --nvarchar
FROM
    TableA AS a
    TableB AS b
WHERE
COALESCE(CAST(a.number AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 0) <> COALESCE(CAST(b.number AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 0)
```